# kivy garden mapview methode to draw itinirary

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, kivy

i'm new to `kivy`, in `Mapview` a want to show the **itinirary** like googlemap does.

i want a result similaire to this photo :

[image]

a searched in mapview methodes and it dones not provide similaire thing.

i tried to create multiple markers like thhis :

```html
        MapView:
            id: mapview
            lat: 36.77418821888212
            lon: 3.052954737671183
            zoom: 12
            on_zoom:
                self.zoom = 12 if self.zoom < 12 else self.zoom

            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                
                lat: 36.7571627
                lon: 2.9946709

            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"Resources/ptn (2).png"
                lat: 36.735850
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320
            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"Resources/ptn (2).png"
                lat: 36.735900
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320
            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"Resources/ptn (2).png"
                lat: 36.735950
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320
            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"Resources/ptn (2).png"
                lat: 36.736000
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320
            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"Resources/ptn (2).png"
                lat: 36.736050
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320
            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"Resources/ptn (2).png"
                lat: 36.736100
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320

            MapMarkerPopup:#ljama3 lakbir
                source:"source/marker.png"
                lat: 36.735848
                lon: 3.138329
                popup_size: 400,320
```

but when i `zoom IN` it does not look like a line but points next to each other

so my questions is what are the possible solutions to this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw lines on the `MapView` just as you would any other `Widget`. By extending `MapView`, you can draw lines like this:

```
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    MyMapView:
        m1: marker1
        m2: marker2
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        pos_hint: {'y':0.1}
        zoom: 15
        lat: 36.77418821888212
        lon: 3.052954737671183
        double_tap_zoom: True
        MapMarker:
            id: marker1
            lat: 36.77418821888212
            lon: 3.052954737671183
            on_release: app.marker_released(self)
        MapMarker:
            id: marker2
            lat:  36.77
            lon: 3.06
            on_release: app.marker_released(self)
            
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        text: 'info'
        on_release: app.info()
'''

class MyMapView(MapView):
    grp = ObjectProperty(None)

    def do_update(self, dt):  # this over-rides the do_update() method of MapView
        super(MyMapView, self).do_update(dt)
        self.draw_lines()

    # draw the lines
    def draw_lines(self):
        points = [[self.m1.center_x, self.m1.y], [self.m2.center_x, self.m2.y]]  # get the points for the lines from somewhere
        lines = Line()
        lines.points = points
        lines.width = 2
        if self.grp is not None:
            # just update the group with updated lines lines
            self.grp.clear()
            self.grp.add(lines)
        else:
            with self.canvas.after:
                #  create the group and add the lines
                Color(1,0,0,1)  # line color
                self.grp = InstructionGroup()
                self.grp.add(lines)


class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def info(self, *args):
        print(self.root.ids.marker1)
        print(self.root.ids.marker2)

    def marker_released(self, marker):
        print(marker)

MapViewApp().run()
```

Comment: plz, i'm new to kivy, can you give me a exemple of this working, because i can't make it work...

Comment: In your `kv`, replace `MapView` with `MyMapView`. Then, in the code I posted, replace `points = ` with two points. Try something like `points = [[50,50], [150,150]]` just to see if it works. In my code, `self.m1` and `self.m2` are `MapMarker` widgets.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a complete example. Note that this is just a proof of the concept that you can draw lines. It still has bugs, like it won't draw correctly if one of the markers is off screen.

Comment: @JohnAnderson - this worked for me. What I'm wondering is, how do you fix these bugs? The line moves when you go "off screen" Thanks